# Can I use two additional Apple Thunderbolt Displays at 60 Hz with my MacBook Pro Mid 2014?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display

Which is the maximal refreshment rate for two connected Thunderbolt Displays? I want to connect them via Mini-Display-Port to the Thunderbolt Ports of my MacBook Pro 15" Mid 2014. I want to use the maximum resolution (2560 px) on both TB Displays. Is it possible to run them both at 60 Hz and max. resolution?

Comment: If you didn't buy the displays yet, a TB display update might be imminent, just fyi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Everymac](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.8-15-dual-graphics-mid-2014-retina-display-specs.html)

> This model supports a simultaneous maximum resolution up to 2560x1600 on two external displays via Thunderbolt. Alternately, it can support a single display up to 2560x1600 via Thunderbolt and a single 1080p display at up to 60 Hz, 3840x2160 at 30 Hz, or 4096x2160 at 24 Hz via HDMI.

…so I'd say 'yes'.